# Google Colab does not see .so files

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, google-colaboratory

I`m trying to make a CUDA extension to use it in Python in Google Colab.

This is setup.py

```
sources = [os.path.join(path_to_cpp, 'interface.cpp'),
            os.path.join(path_to_cpp, 'box_encoder_cuda.cu'),
            os.path.join(path_to_cpp, 'random_horiz_flip.cu')]

setup(
    name='SSD',
    ext_modules=[
        CUDAExtension(
            'SSD._C', 
            sources)
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    })
```

When I build this I can clearly see that libc10.so was present in the build

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,- 
z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format- 
security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/content/drive/My  
Drive/SSD/csrc/interface.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/content/drive/My Drive/SSD/csrc/box_encoder_cuda.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/content/drive/My  
Drive/SSD/csrc/random_horiz_flip.o -L/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib - 
L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lc10 -ltorch -ltorch_cpu -ltorch_python -lcudart -lc10_cuda -ltorch_cuda -o  
build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/SSD/_C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

However if I try to use it in Colab:

```
%%writefile test.py
import SSD._C

print("All ok")
```

```
!python test.py
```

I will see the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import SSD._C
ImportError: libc10.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Maybe it happens because libraries were not declared in the Python runtime, and I have to declare them somehow? Thank you in advance!

P.S.
When I try to use it directly in cell, without writing to a .py file:

```
import SSD._C

print("All ok")
```

it yields

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SSD'
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by importing torch before importing the extension:

```
%%writefile test.py
import torch
import SSD._C

print("All ok")
```

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) "this will resolve some symbols that the dynamic linker must see".

However, why this extension cannot be used directly in .ipynb cell is still an open point.

**Edit:** If you install a new extension in the .ipynb, make sure to restart runtime before you use it. After restart, you will be able to use the new extension in .ipynb cells